# Linq - Ordering Json Products by Price Double

Tags: c#, json, linq, oop

i Have this the products table:

```
P_Id    P_Title P_JsonData  P_SC_Id
 168    fdsfdf  SomeJson    1
```

SomeJson equals:

```
{
"pType": "1",
"pTitle": "son 1",
"pProds": [{
    "formM": 1,
    "sDesc": "<p>son 1</p>",
    "lDesc": "<p>son 1<br></p>",
    "pColor": "",
    "pSize": "XXS",
    "postage": "22",
    "quatity": 23,
    "aPrice": "23",
    "rPrice": "23",
    "Discounted": "23",
    "Price": "23",
    "p_Num": "71770005f28641118a617ba8ec070a44",
    "images": [{
        "mN": 1,
        "idImage": "image1",
        "fileName": "1724d443fe514050903176247d379e09.jpg",
        "bytes": "/img/ProdImages/71770005f28641118a617ba8ec070a44/1724d443fe514050903176247d379e09.jpg"
    }, {
        "mN": 1,
        "idImage": "image2",
        "fileName": "f70d2e941fd740c5bd72cb451c04b81b.jpg",
        "bytes": "/img/ProdImages/71770005f28641118a617ba8ec070a44/f70d2e941fd740c5bd72cb451c04b81b.jpg"
    }, {
        "mN": 1,
        "idImage": "image3",
        "fileName": "4c58e7b0406b48c89fcd5fabe151205a.jpg",
        "bytes": "/img/ProdImages/71770005f28641118a617ba8ec070a44/4c58e7b0406b48c89fcd5fabe151205a.jpg"
    }]
}, {
    "formM": 2,
    "sDesc": "<p>son 2</p>",
    "lDesc": "<p>son 2<br></p>",
    "pColor": "",
    "pSize": "XXS",
    "postage": "3",
    "quatity": 3,
    "aPrice": "3",
    "rPrice": "3",
    "Discounted": "3",
    "Price": "3",
    "p_Num": "7be125c9df94481a84bf1eff928fc2a3",
    "images": [{
        "mN": 2,
        "idImage": "image1",
        "fileName": "c117460b70194788b162d5445f01e151.jpg",
        "bytes": "/img/ProdImages/7be125c9df94481a84bf1eff928fc2a3/c117460b70194788b162d5445f01e151.jpg"
    }, {
        "mN": 2,
        "idImage": "image2",
        "fileName": "5a70893f7e5a401398344d4269f245ce.jpg",
        "bytes": "/img/ProdImages/7be125c9df94481a84bf1eff928fc2a3/5a70893f7e5a401398344d4269f245ce.jpg"
    }]
}, {
    "formM": 0,
    "sDesc": "",
    "lDesc": "",
    "pColor": "",
    "pSize": "0",
    "postage": "0",
    "quatity": 0,
    "aPrice": "0",
    "rPrice": "0",
    "Discounted": "0",
    "Price": "0",
    "p_Num": "1b7752c65d3747ed99562745b875b8da",
    "images": []
}, {
    "formM": 0,
    "sDesc": "",
    "lDesc": "",
    "pColor": "",
    "pSize": "0",
    "postage": "0",
    "quatity": 0,
    "aPrice": "0",
    "rPrice": "0",
    "Discounted": "0",
    "Price": "0",
    "p_Num": "5b817d94b3ec4471a26a0a47a15cc37c",
    "images": []
}]
}
```

This SomeJson Represents the products for each row in the product table so a product can have many products if two products are the same but is differentiated by size and colour so they would have different prices but fit in with the same product.

Now each row in the products table will have this SomeJson, what i need to do is order the json by price so i get the lowest value in element 0 of the SomeJson.

And i want to order by price descending so i get the highest price from the SomeJson at element 0.

I tried this:

### Lowest to Highest Price

```
data = data.OrderBy(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainProduct>(x.P_JsonData).pProds.Where(g => Convert.ToDouble(g.Price) > 0 && g.formM > 0).OrderBy(d => Convert.ToDouble(d.Price)).ElementAt(0).Price).ToList();
```

### Highest to Lowest Price:

```
 data = data.OrderByDescending(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainProduct>(x.P_JsonData).pProds.Where(g => Convert.ToDouble(g.Price) > 0 && g.formM > 0).OrderByDescending(d => d.Price).ElementAt(0).Price).ToList();
```

But no luck

Here are the Objects that make up this product table and json:

```
    public class MainProduct
    {
        public string pType;
        public string pTitle;
        public List<ProductJson> pProds;
        
    }

    public class ProductJson
    {
        public int formM;
        public string sDesc;
        public string lDesc;
        public string pColor;
        public string pSize;
        public string postage;
        public int quatity;
        public string aPrice;
        public string rPrice;
        public string Discounted;
        public string Price;
        public string p_Num;
        public List<ImageJson> images;

    }


    public class ImageJson
    {
        public int mN;
        public string idImage;
        public string fileName;
        public string bytes;
    }
```

So how would i achieve getting the lowest to high and highest to lowest?

Comment: I’m not sure, but can you try breaking into two lines. I mean deserialise it first store in one variable. And then apply OrderBy. It should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the max price value using [`Json.Linq`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) without deserializing JSON to object model

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var maxValue = json["pProds"].Max(token => token["Price"]?.Value<double>());
```

Then you can put it into `OrderBy` statement